# EF 6 (exception) Sequence contains more than one element - Inserting new record

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I check if the record exists. The modelInit variable gets modelInit.Count = 0 when there is no record. I tried to save without checking if the record exists and threw the same exception.

Source

```
public void IncluiModeloIniciativa(ModeloIniciativaAuxiliar model)
{
    ValidateEmptyFields(model);

    int idIniciativa = model.IdIniciativa;
    int idModelo = model.IdModelo;
    List<ModeloIniciativa> modelInit = context.ModelosIniciativas
        .Where(x => x.IdIniciativa == idIniciativa && x.IdModelo == idModelo).ToList();

    if (null != modelInit && modelInit.Count > 0)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(
            Resources.ModeloIniciativaResources.ModeloIniciativaJaExiste);
    }

    try
    {
        context.ModelosIniciativas.Add(new ModeloIniciativa()
        {
            IdIniciativa = model.IdIniciativa,
            IdModelo = model.IdModelo,
            Status = model.StatusMake,
            VLR_INICIATIVA = model.VlrIniciativaMake.Value,
            VLR_APROVADO = model.VlrAprovadoMake.Value,
            VLR_SALDO = model.VlrSaldoMake.Value,
            TipoIniciativa = TipoIniciativa.Make.ToString()
        });

        context.ModelosIniciativas.Add(new ModeloIniciativa()
        {
            IdIniciativa = model.IdIniciativa,
            IdModelo = model.IdModelo,
            Status = model.StatusBuy,
            VLR_INICIATIVA = model.VlrIniciativaBuy.Value,
            VLR_APROVADO = model.VlrAprovadoBuy.Value,
            VLR_SALDO = model.VlrSaldoBuy.Value,
            TipoIniciativa = TipoIniciativa.Buy.ToString()
        });

        context.ModelosIniciativas.Add(new ModeloIniciativa()
        {
            IdIniciativa = model.IdIniciativa,
            IdModelo = model.IdModelo,
            Status = model.StatusRnD,
            VLR_INICIATIVA = model.VlrIniciativaRnD.Value,
            VLR_APROVADO = model.VlrAprovadoRnD.Value,
            VLR_SALDO = model.VlrSaldoRnD.Value,
            TipoIniciativa = TipoIniciativa.RnD.ToString()
        });

        context.ModelosIniciativas.Add(new ModeloIniciativa()
        {
            IdIniciativa = model.IdIniciativa,
            IdModelo = model.IdModelo,
            Status = model.StatusCodesign,
            VLR_INICIATIVA = model.VlrIniciativaCodesign.Value,
            VLR_APROVADO = model.VlrAprovadoCodesign.Value,
            VLR_SALDO = model.VlrSaldoCodesign.Value,
            TipoIniciativa = TipoIniciativa.Codesign.ToString()
        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


}
```

[Edited]

```
public BHX.Application.Logs.Models.Entity GetOrCreateEntity(Type type)
{
    var logEntidade = this.AuditionContext.Entities.SingleOrDefault(entidade => entidade.Name == type.FullName);
    if (logEntidade == null)
    {
        //Se for um subsite, deve pegar o caminho do site principal considerando o caminho até a última barra.
        string caminhoSitePrincipal = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        logEntidade = this.AuditionContext.Entities.Create();
        logEntidade.Name = type.FullName;
        logEntidade.AssemblyPath = @"bin\" + type.Assembly.ManifestModule.ToString();
        this.AuditionContext.Entities.Add(logEntidade);
    }
    return logEntidade;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at BHX.ClienteGroup.eProgram.DataAccess.ECContext.GetOrCreateEntity(Type type) in C:\Projetos RTC\e-Program\W130_PRINCIPAL\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\DataAccess\ECContext.Auditing.cs:line 113
   at BHX.ClienteGroup.eProgram.DataAccess.ECContext.saveEntryOperation(DbEntityEntry item, EntityState state) in C:\Projetos RTC\e-Program\W130_PRINCIPAL\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\DataAccess\ECContext.Auditing.cs:line 99
   at BHX.ClienteGroup.eProgram.DataAccess.ECContext.SavePrograms(Boolean auditing) in C:\Projetos RTC\e-Program\W130_PRINCIPAL\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\DataAccess\ECContext.Auditing.cs:line 72
   at BHX.ClienteGroup.eProgram.DataAccess.ECContext.SavePrograms() in C:\Projetos RTC\e-Program\W130_PRINCIPAL\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\DataAccess\ECContext.Auditing.cs:line 35
   at BHX.ClienteGroup.eProgram.Services.ModeloIniciativaServices.IncluiModeloIniciativa(ModeloIniciativaAuxiliar model) in C:\Projetos RTC\e-Program\W130_PRINCIPAL\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\Services\ModeloIniciativaServices.cs:line 204
```

Comment: Can you show your `GetOrCreateEntity` method?

Comment: You have more than one entity with the same `name`, `SingleOrDefault` search for an entity with supplied conditions and ensures there is at most one instance of object that satisfies that conditions, if there is more it throws an exception

Comment: You're right. The Audit saved the entity's name more than once. I deleted and stopped throwing the exception. I'll ask to the architect to fix the audity library. Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you use Single or SingleOrDefault for a table and the result is more than one element, then will throw this exception. See the cell that the SaveChanges in ECContext is customized to save audit logs. Check how it saves these logs, why should not have a single key or not this checking the registry existence and saving more than once. You may not be using the custom method correctly.

Comment: You are right. There's a method called save() that do something before call the custom SaveChanges. These methods has customized by our architect.